# Multiplying z values in linestringz shapefile with a constant

Tags: shapefile, convert, 3d, linestring

I have National Levee Data (NLD) shapefile for the entire US in a linestringZ format. The unit of Z values in the shapefile is in feet, but I need it in meters. So, I want to multiply all z values with 0.3048 to have the elevations in meters. What tool could I use to do this multiplication? Or any other ways to do this conversion.

Comment: What software do you have available? Theoretically if the vertical units are defined as feet a quick project to a CRS with the vertical units of metres should work, how to do that depends on what software you have available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy Python solution for you. Only requires the installation of GeoPandas. Just substitute your filepaths and run this script.

```py
import geopandas

inputFile = '/home/lpowalka/Documents/dane/prg/Województwa_pop.shp'
outputFile = '/home/lpowalka/Documents/dane/prg/Województwa_pop_new.shp'
df = geopandas.read_file(inputFile)
   
zfactor = 0.3048
df.geometry = df.geometry.scale(zfact=zfactor)

df.to_file(outputFile)
```